# navbar-full actual use in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

navbar-full is not making any difference given the code below

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light bg-faded">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Full width</a>
</nav>
```

the navbar is still full width with or without navbar-full. Can someone help explain this?

Comment: in bottstrap css `navbar-full` is used to remove rounded corners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [bootstrap](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#placement) documentation

> Navbars can be statically placed (their default behavior), static without rounded corners, or fixed to the top or bottom of the viewport.

and the respective examples are:

to remove rounded corners

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-full navbar-light bg-faded">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Full width</a>
</nav>
```

for fixed top

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed top</a>
</nav>
```

from bootstap css

```
.navbar-full {
    border-radius:0;
}
```

So, I believe, `navbar-full` is to remove rounded corners.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find `.navbar-full` in `bootstrap.css`, because `.navbar-full` is not the default bootstrap class. To make full with or box, change `.container` class to `.container-fluid`

[Reference link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)